# grails+spring-security-facebook listen to login success event

Tags: facebook, spring, facebook-graph-api, grails, spring-security

im a newbie both in spring security and  spring-security-facebook  and in an app  that  we are building we have  to couple them.Everything is working well i will need to know the way to listen to the facebook login success event. is there some one that already did a stuff that impose him to catch the facebook event success?? I need that because  in the begining of the app (before adding the spring -security-Facebook plugin ); we have a special behaviour attached to the "grails.plugins.springsecurity.onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent"  event (configured in the config.groovy file) and we have to execute the same special behaviour when the user connect with facebook account. Is there an event (extending springsecurity kinds of events) that we have to listen to?

any idea ??

Ps: when searching for solution we found a way to catch the FB js Events and work around to reach what we want as result  but we  would as possible to want to not go that way ....

Answer (score 0):

The problem with it that current Spring Security Facebook authenticates user on each request (by listening to FB cookie, transparently), so you'll get this event on each request. Probably it's not what you want, right? It the same as having a filter on each request.

Btw, you can handle situation when user login into your app first time, but implementing `onCreate(user, token)` or `afterCreate(user, token)` in service `FacebookAuthService` (you have to create such service at this case)

---

Example:

File `grails-app/services/FacebookAuthService.groovy`:

```
class FacebookAuthService {

    void afterCreate(def user, def token) {
        log.info("New user!") //or any code there
    }

}
```

Comment: The solution you give (implementing our own  oncreate(user, token) and afterCreate(user, token) inside the faceBookAuthService) may help us a lot

Comment: FacebookAuthService it's optinal service that you can create (not exists by default) to control plugin behaviour

Comment: OK can you give me a simple example please cause i still dont see how to code this service and how to listen to the facebook login success event ? since those methods are in the "FacebookAuthService" are they called based on a filter ?? sorry but im just missing the work flow ... can you post me a little example .. thanks in advance...